# Full Event Sourcing in preventing loss of domain event published to event bus subscribed by other microservicess

Tags: architecture, rabbitmq, nservicebus, event-sourcing

I across the article below, and want to find out exactly how full event sourcing pattern can prevent the issue of losing event when publishing domain event to event bus.

> For this scenario, using the full Event Sourcing (ES) pattern is one
>   of the best approaches, if not the best.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/subscribe-events

Specifically, the scenario is that Catalog microservice updated a product price and published a ProductPRiceChanged event. How can full ES prevent loss of that event.

[image: .net]

Comment: The linked document does not claim that event loss can be prevented. The words "loss" and "prevent" are not contained in it. And maybe this question is mor OT on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do you know how full ES works? If so, please do explain. I can move it to there or other furm.